# How can I cast Memory<T> to another

Tags: c#

We can cast `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` to another using [MemoryMarshal.Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast) method overloads. Like :

```
Span<byte> span = stackalloc byte[4];
var singleIntSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, int>(span);
```

But is there any way to cast `Memory<T>` to another? for example cast `Memory<byte>` to `Memory<ushort>`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do it *directly*; however, if you *really need*, you can create a custom `MemoryManager<T>` (presumably actually a `MyMemoryManager<TFrom, TTo> : MemoryManager<TTo>` that performs the cast as part of the `GetSpan()` override. This is slightly non-trivial, and demands another allocation - unlike a `Span<T>` cast, which is allocation-free.

If you need a concrete example of that, I can whip one up (I actually do exactly this in some existing code), but: to be honest, you probably want to reconsider the scenario instead.

Edit: something like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Memory<byte> bytes = new byte[1024];

        Memory<ushort> typed = Utils.Cast<byte, ushort>(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(typed.Length); // 512

        // note CPU endianness matters re the layout
        typed.Span[0] = 0x5432;
        Console.WriteLine(bytes.Span[0]); // 50 = 0x32
        Console.WriteLine(bytes.Span[1]); // 84 = 0x54
    }
}

static class Utils
{
    public static Memory<TTo> Cast<TFrom, TTo>(Memory<TFrom> from)
        where TFrom : unmanaged
        where TTo : unmanaged
    {
        // avoid the extra allocation/indirection, at the cost of a gen-0 box
        if (typeof(TFrom) == typeof(TTo)) return (Memory<TTo>)(object)from;

        return new CastMemoryManager<TFrom, TTo>(from).Memory;
    }
    private sealed class CastMemoryManager<TFrom, TTo> : MemoryManager<TTo>
        where TFrom : unmanaged
        where TTo : unmanaged
    {
        private readonly Memory<TFrom> _from;

        public CastMemoryManager(Memory<TFrom> from) => _from = from;

        public override Span<TTo> GetSpan()
            => MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom, TTo>(_from.Span);

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { }
        public override MemoryHandle Pin(int elementIndex = 0)
            => throw new NotSupportedException();
        public override void Unpin()
            => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

If you really want to support pin/unpin, that should be possible - you'll just need to compute the relative ranges and offsets from the competing `TFrom`/`TTo`, though - presumably using `Unsafe.SizeOf<T>` etc, and using `MemoryMarshal.TryGetMemoryManager` to get the underlying memory manager (if one - note that naked arrays don't have a memory manager). Unless you're going to extensively test that option, throwing is probably safer than getting it wrong.

Comment: Wow this is awesome, i have been wracking my brain at a solution to this, there is a lot virgins being sacrificed in this dark magic!

Comment: What is `L0 box`?

Comment: @usr sorry, I meant gen-0 - i.e. an object (the box) that will be GC-collectable immediately (when the next gen-0 sweep happens), never surviving into a later generation

Comment: i guess the MemoryManager is taking care of ownership transferal and negating the use-after-free bugs that could happen

Comment: @MichaelRandall nope, it isn't; basically, a `Memory<T>` is just an offset+count, and an `object` reference. That `object` *can* be a `T[]`, but it can also be a `MemoryManager<T>`. If it is the latter, then the *actual* span is `((MemoryManager<T>)obj).GetSpan().Slice(offset, count)`; if it is an array, then it is `new Span<T>((T[])obj, offset, count)`. Nothing more than that. Any ownership etc is completely separate.

Comment: @MarcGravell, isn't throwing NotSupportedException() inside Pin() and Unpin() an anti-pattern?

Comment: @moien good question, but the way I see it: a full pin/unpin implementation would require a lot more code than I care to write for this example, with interlocked counters, a tracked `MemoryHandle`, and all the math to compare the sizes of `TFrom`/`TTo`. So... "exercise for reader"

Comment: @MarcGravell What if we need to get from `string` to `Memory<byte>` for `stream.WriteAsync`? IOW, how do we deal with ReadOnlyMemory?

Comment: @Zach you'll need to rent and encode, or look at utf8string in .net core 5

Comment: @MarcGravell Ignore the string to Memory<byte> - what if it's just ReadOnlyMemory of int to byte?

Comment: @ZachSaw then: `MemoryMarshal.Cast` should have you covered

Comment: @MarcGravell Not sure I follow - `MemoryMarshal.Cast` does not have an overload that would take `ReadOnlyMemory`?

Comment: @Zach it can take a `ReadOnlySpan<TFrom>`, though - so just use `.Span` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast?view=netcore-3.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_MemoryMarshal_Cast__2_System_ReadOnlySpan___0__. - or do you mean "to get the value as a memory of the cast type"? That is trickier, but possible - pretty much exactly like in the answer above. Note we also have `AsMemory` which removes the "read only" if needed

Comment: @MarcGravell I am in Zach's situation. Why is casting a `Span<T>` so much easier compared to `Memory<T>`? The types are nearly the same.

Comment: @BrunoZell because a `Memory<T>` wraps either a `T[]` array or a `MemoryOwner<T>`; a `double[]` is not a `byte[]`, and a `MemoryOwner<double>` is not a `MemoryOwner<byte>` - so it has no way of talking to the owner. This problem goes away once you have dereferenced the span

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Unsafe.As` to cast `Memory<TFrom>` to `Memory<TTo>` but you would need to take care of the correct length of `Memory<TTo>`:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

// test data
var floatData = new float[5];
var floatMemory = floatData.AsMemory();
floatMemory.Span.Fill(1.99f);

// cast
var resizeFactor = sizeof(double) / sizeof(float);

var doubleMemory = Unsafe
    .As<Memory<float>, Memory<double>>(ref floatMemory)
    .Slice(0, floatMemory.Length / resizeFactor);
```

Edit: this works as long as the byte size of `TTo` is larger or equal to `TFrom`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can, however I guess you can return a span from it, though i doubt it will help

[Memory.Span Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1.span?view=netcore-2.2)

> Returns a span from the current instance.

```
var array = new int[4];
var mem = array.AsMemory();
var span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, byte>(mem.Span);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already mentioned the 'Span<T>' casting.

Comment: there are ways... but they're evil - see my answer