# How to serialize to the given TextWriter instance using System.Text.Json?

Tags: .net-core, system.text.json

I know how to serialize to a `Stream`, but is it possible to serialize to a `TextWriter`?

The problem is that `TextWriter` does not expose a `Stream` object.

It seems there is no such option, but maybe I am missing something.

**EDIT 1**

Please, allow me to clarify. I know `TextWriter` does not expose a `Stream` object, because there are `TextWriter` implementations that do not have an underlying stream. That is the gist of this question - can we serialize to a `TextWriter` using `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: System.Text.Json is designed to serialize directly from and to utf8 byte streams, not utf16 char streams.  There's no `TextWriter` support built in.  Also, `TextWriter` does not expose a `Stream` because there are TextWriters that do not write to streams. e.g. `StringWriter`.

Comment: But if you know you have an underling Stream, why are you using a TextWriter?  Any chance you're actually trying to serialize to a stream with some specified encoding other than utf8?

Comment: I do not have an underlying stream. I must have phrased my question poorly.

Comment: Then no, I'm not aware of anything built-in to do that, for confirmation see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-6.0) and/or [this search](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/search?q=textwriter%20path:src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json).

Comment: As far as I know whenever System.Text.Json needs to serialize to some encoding other than utf8 they use [`Encoding.CreateTranscodingStream()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/search?q=CreateTranscodingStream), e.g. [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/System.Net.Http.Json/src/System/Net/Http/Json/JsonContentOfT.cs#L57).

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: There is always a problem with negative answers - how can one know if it is the final answer? But for now - yes. If you arrange it as an answer I will credit you. I can always change my vote if a better answer arrives.

Comment: I have made an API Proposal about adding a way to wrap a TextWriter in a Stream: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/98987

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to serialize directly to a `TextWriter` using System.Text.Json as of .NET 6.  For confirmation:

1. In [*Try the new System.Text.Json APIs*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/), Immo Landwerth of MSFT wrote,

   > We needed a new set of JSON APIs that are highly tuned for performance by using Span and can process UTF-8 directly without having to transcode to UTF-16 string instances.

   I.e. not needing to serialize to some intermediate `TextWriter` was a design requirement.
2. No override of [`JsonSerializer.Serialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-6.0) or [`JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializeasync?view=net-6.0) takes a `TextWriter`.
3. The search ['textwriter path:src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json' in dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/search?q=textwriter%20path:src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json) currently returns nothing.

   For comparison, searching for `Stream` in the same path returns [16 code results](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/search?q=Stream%20path:src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json).
4. Whenever .NET needs to serialize to a `Stream` using some encoding other than UTF8, they do so via [`Encoding.CreateTranscodingStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.createtranscodingstream?view=net-6.0) rather than via a `StreamWriter`; see [this search](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/search?q=CreateTranscodingStream) for examples.

Thus the most straightforward way to serialize to a `TextWriter` using System.Text.Json would be to serialize to a `string`, then write that to the `TextWriter`.

If for some reason this causes prohibitively bad performance (e.g. because the intermediate strings would be large enough to go on the [large object heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) and cause memory fragmentation or garbage collection slowdowns) you could wrap your `TextWriter` in some synthetic `Stream` that takes the incoming bytes, interprets each pair as Unicode characters, and writes them to the `TextWriter`.  Then that `Stream` could be in turn wrapped by a transcoding stream that accepts UTF8 and passed to `JsonSerializer` as shown in the following extension methods:

```cs
public static partial class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static void Serialize<TValue>(TextWriter textWriter, TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions? options = default)
    {
        if (textWriter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(textWriter));
        using (var stream = textWriter.AsWrappedWriteOnlyStream(Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(stream, value, options);
        }
    }
    
    public static async Task SerializeAsync<TValue>(TextWriter textWriter, TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions? options = default, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (textWriter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(textWriter));
        await using (var stream = textWriter.AsWrappedWriteOnlyStream(Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, value, options);
        }
    }
}

public static partial class TextExtensions
{
    public static Encoding PlatformCompatibleUnicode { get; } = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? Encoding.Unicode : Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
    public static bool IsPlatformCompatibleUnicode(this Encoding encoding) => BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? encoding.CodePage == 1200 : encoding.CodePage == 1201;

    public static Stream AsWrappedWriteOnlyStream(this TextWriter textWriter, Encoding outerEncoding, bool leaveOpen = false)
    {
        if (textWriter == null || outerEncoding == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        Encoding innerEncoding;
        if (textWriter is StringWriter)
            innerEncoding = PlatformCompatibleUnicode;
        else
            innerEncoding = textWriter.Encoding ?? throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("No encoding for {0}", textWriter));
        
        return outerEncoding.IsPlatformCompatibleUnicode()
            ? new TextWriterStream(textWriter, leaveOpen)
            : Encoding.CreateTranscodingStream(new TextWriterStream(textWriter, leaveOpen), innerEncoding, outerEncoding, false);
    }
}

sealed class TextWriterStream : Stream
{
    // By sealing UnicodeTextWriterStream we avoid a lot of the complexity of MemoryStream.
    TextWriter textWriter;
    bool leaveOpen;
    Nullable<byte> lastByte = null;

    public TextWriterStream(TextWriter textWriter, bool leaveOpen) => (this.textWriter, this.leaveOpen) = (textWriter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(), leaveOpen);

    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;
    
    public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Position { get => throw new NotSupportedException(); set => throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override int Read(Span<byte> buffer) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override int ReadByte() => throw new NotSupportedException();

    bool TryPopLastHalfChar(byte b, out char ch)
    {
        if (lastByte != null)
        {
            Span<byte> tempBuffer = stackalloc byte [2];
            tempBuffer[0] = lastByte.Value; tempBuffer[1] = b;
            ch = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, char>(tempBuffer)[0];
            lastByte = null;
            return true;
        }
        ch = default;
        return false;
    }

    void PushLastHalfChar(byte b) 
    {
        if (lastByte != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Last half character is already saved.");
        this.lastByte = b;
    }

    void EnsureOpen()
    {
        if (textWriter == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
    }
    
    static void Flush(TextWriter textWriter, Nullable<byte> lastByte)
    {
        if (lastByte != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Attempt to flush writer with pending byte {0}", (int)lastByte));
        textWriter?.Flush();
    }
    
    static Task FlushAsync(TextWriter textWriter, Nullable<byte> lastByte, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (lastByte != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempt to flush writer with pending byte");
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return Task.FromCanceled(cancellationToken);
        return textWriter.FlushAsync(); // No overload takes a cancellation token?
    }
    
    public override void Flush() 
    {
        EnsureOpen();
        Flush(textWriter, lastByte);
    }
    
    public override Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        EnsureOpen();
        return FlushAsync(textWriter, lastByte, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        ValidateBufferArgs(buffer, offset, count);
        Write(buffer.AsSpan(offset, count));
    }

    public override void Write(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer)
    {
        EnsureOpen();
        if (buffer.Length < 1)
            return;
        if (TryPopLastHalfChar(buffer[0], out var ch))
        {
            textWriter.Write(ch);
            buffer = buffer.Slice(1);
        }
        if (buffer.Length % 2 != 0)
        {
            PushLastHalfChar(buffer[buffer.Length - 1]);
            buffer = buffer.Slice(0, buffer.Length - 1);
        }
        if (buffer.Length > 0)
            textWriter.Write(MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, char>(buffer));
    }

    public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ValidateBufferArgs(buffer, offset, count);
        return WriteAsync(buffer.AsMemory(offset, count)).AsTask();
    }

    public override ValueTask WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return ValueTask.FromCanceled(cancellationToken);
        try
        {
            return WriteAsyncCore(buffer, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
        {
            return new ValueTask(Task.FromCanceled(oce.CancellationToken));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return ValueTask.FromException(exception);
        }
    }

    async ValueTask WriteAsyncCore(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        EnsureOpen();
        if (buffer.Length < 1)
            return;
        if (TryPopLastHalfChar(buffer.Span[0], out var ch))
        {
            await textWriter.WriteAsync(ch);
            buffer = buffer.Slice(1);
        }
        if (buffer.Length % 2 != 0)
        {
            PushLastHalfChar(buffer.Span[buffer.Length - 1]);
            buffer = buffer.Slice(0, buffer.Length - 1);
        }
        if (buffer.Length > 0)
            await textWriter.WriteAsync(Utils.Cast<byte, char>(buffer), cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (disposing) 
            {
                var textWriter = Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.textWriter!, null);
                if (textWriter != null)
                {
                    Flush(textWriter, lastByte);
                    if (!leaveOpen)
                        textWriter.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        finally 
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }   

    public override async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        var textWriter = Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.textWriter!, null);
        if (textWriter != null)
        {
            await FlushAsync(textWriter, lastByte, CancellationToken.None);
            if (!leaveOpen)
                await textWriter.DisposeAsync();
        }
        await base.DisposeAsync();
    }

    static void ValidateBufferArgs(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(buffer));
        if (offset < 0 || count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        if (count > buffer.Length - offset)
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}

public static class Utils
{
    // Adapted for read only memory from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54512940/3744182
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511330/how-can-i-cast-memoryt-to-another
    public static ReadOnlyMemory<TTo> Cast<TFrom, TTo>(ReadOnlyMemory<TFrom> from)
        where TFrom : unmanaged
        where TTo : unmanaged
    {
        // avoid the extra allocation/indirection, at the cost of a gen-0 box
        if (typeof(TFrom) == typeof(TTo)) return (ReadOnlyMemory<TTo>)(object)from;

        return new CastMemoryManager<TFrom, TTo>(MemoryMarshal.AsMemory(from)).Memory;
    }
    private sealed class CastMemoryManager<TFrom, TTo> : MemoryManager<TTo>
        where TFrom : unmanaged
        where TTo : unmanaged
    {
        private readonly Memory<TFrom> _from;

        public CastMemoryManager(Memory<TFrom> from) => _from = from;

        public override Span<TTo> GetSpan() => MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom, TTo>(_from.Span);

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { }
        public override MemoryHandle Pin(int elementIndex = 0) => throw new NotSupportedException();
        public override void Unpin() => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And now you will be able to do something like:

```
JsonSerializerExtensions.Serialize(textWriter, someObject);
```

But I'm not sure all this effort is worth it in all honesty.

Notes:

- Not tested on big-endian platforms (which are [rare](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3685624/3744182)).
- Could use more async testing.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LMoI7K).